# What do we mean by "resources" and should this be distinguished from references?

Tags: discussion

One of the comments on [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7345/introduction-to-jazz-theory) about sources of information about Jazz Theory suggests that the question is off topic because it is a shopping request.  I looked at the [FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/faq) and it indicates somewhat vaguely that:

> requesting a list of resources

is off topic.

What specifically is meant by `resources` is this context and does this exclude asking questions about where to find information on topics that would be too broad to cover in a standard answer but too specialized to easily find resources.

Note: I am not necessarily defending the question above, since I think it is borderline and one could probably get a decent start with Google, but I could imagine requesting information about more specific aspects of jazz theory that could not be covered effectively in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally,the resource is us.  If they have many questions in a broad area they can ask them here one at a time.  If it's a general thing where they want resources for learning X, they should ask "How can I learn X?".  We're problem solvers rather that resource-finders, and may provide other solutions besides the asker's predetermined solution of studying Y resources.  If those resources are the best way, an answer to the "How can I?" will provide them.  Asking the wrong way around (about Y instead of X) is often a problem on SE and other Q&A sites, and it makes it hard to effectively solve the underlying issue or to understand where the user is coming from and provide answers within that context.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at these two questions of mine ([bad: shopping request](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/repertoire-recommendation-for-beginning-viola) / [better: what to look for at this level of experience](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9493/what-to-look-for-in-beginner-etudes-for-a-second-instrument)). These straddle the line pretty closely. But the biggest difference in the good question is that it provides enough background for the answers to *un-ask* the specific question (what I *thought* I needed), and provide better guidance (what I *really* needed, and was trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you linked to this question because the poster mentions Math.SE's reference-request tag.  It's interesting to me that they've found a way to handle this issue there.