# Should [tag:learning-resources] posts still be considered on-topic or made off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, topics

The question [Reading list for music theory for a self taught](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114846/reading-list-for-music-theory-for-a-self-taught) was closed as off-topic (including a close vote from me). However, in updating the tags, I noticed our guidance for [learning-resources](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources):

> ... asking about the existence or availability of certain types of resources (e.g., "what apps are available for learning to hear intervals?") is fine.

By this standard, there is a very compelling case that the question should not have been closed and should be reopened. The underlying issue of "equipment requests" dovetails with the discussion in [Our “recommendations for specific equipment” rule seems to be catching cases beyond those looking for a brand/model recommendation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/our-recommendations-for-specific-equipment-rule-seems-to-be-catching-cases-bey) and has been previously addressed but not (definitively) resolved in [Should external resource lists be allowed on the site?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-external-resource-lists-be-allowed-on-the-site).

Although I believe these questions are valuable, I think they're not a good fit for the this site, as they are highly opinion based and prone to lengthy lists of possibilities.

**SUGGESTIONS:**

1. Rewrite the tag guidance to exclude the current exception.
2. Update [My Question was closed a software/equipment recommendation. What does that mean and what can I do?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/my-question-was-closed-a-software-equipment-recommendation-what-does-that-mean?cb=1) to include this case.
3. Consider burninating [learning-resources](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources) (this would require reviewing the 36 [currently] questions using this tag to see if there are appropriate use cases. I am happy to do that an update with proposals if the discussion here supports looking into burnination).

---

As of 16 June 2021, there are 34 questions tagged [learning-resources](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources). I would put them into the following categories:

- Questions that run afoul of our guideline against resource/equipment requests and either are closed or should be (IMO) (some in this group have been closed as opinion-based or other reasons, rather than equipment requests).

  - Questions that are very broad requests, prone to numerous different answers
  - Questions that seem highly specific, less prone to answers that just list resources
- Questions that present as resource requests, but could be re-cast to retain their meaning in a useful way but exclude the explicit request for resources.
- Questions that don't explicitly request resources, but where answers could well include them.
- Questions about specific resources, but not requests for resources.
- Questions that should not have been tagged with [learning-resources](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources)

Comment: Two related threads: [What's the the learning-resources tag for?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2949/70803); [What do we mean by “resources” and should this be distinguished from references?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/505/70803).

Answer (score 4):

This has similar problems to the old identification tag where most of its uses were off-topic. I suggest we get rid of the tag we can even edit it as a do not use tag while we try to figure out if a different tag needs to be used to replace a subset of questions.

Comment: I see you've just begun removing [learning-resources] tags. If it's okay with you, I'll also start going through my list and making adjustments.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah I just saw two that the tag didn't really make sense on